# How to read data when length is unknown?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio

I'm currently using boost::asio to read data across network connections but settled on a pattern I feel is inneficient:

```
auto listener::read(std::function<void(std::error_code ec, packet packet)> callback) noexcept -> void {
  m_buffer.resize(1);
  m_buffer.shrink_to_fit();

  asio::async_read(*m_socket, asio::buffer(m_buffer), asio::transfer_exactly(1),
                   [&, callback](std::error_code ec, std::size_t length) {
                     const auto available = m_socket->available();
                     packet tmp;
                     tmp.resize(available);
                     asio::async_read(*m_socket, asio::buffer(tmp), asio::transfer_exactly(available));
                     tmp.insert(tmp.begin(), std::make_move_iterator(m_buffer.begin()),
                                std::make_move_iterator(m_buffer.end()));
                     callback(ec, std::move(tmp));
                   });
}
```

(`packet` is `std::vector<unsigned char>`)

I'm not sure how to create this without the temporary. I can't resize `m_buffer` at the beginning because I don't know how much data is coming. I tried to use `m_buffer` only resizing within the lambda to match `available` + 1 but I just end up losing the first byte stored in `m_buffer`.

Is there a more efficient way to do this when expecting a packet of unknown length?

Comment: `packet packet` this is valid?

Comment: @user463035818 [Sadly so](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac85a14ac4e1c10d) (but it's a bad naming choice)

Comment: Not familiar with this part of boost but generally if you don't know how much data is coming before the data transmission that's fairly bad design on the senders part. Ideally the sender should prepend the data with the length of the data so you can allocate accordingly.

If this is impossible you basically just have to guess, allocate a big chunk of memory, read until end of stream or that chunk is full, put that chunk somewhere else and start reading again to your buffer, repeat steps until EOS then combine chunks.

Comment: @rafix07 this is the read from the question you answered yesterday. It's a lambda.

Comment: To echo @Prodigle, if there's an upper bound to how much you are transferring you can just resize to that much, read it in one go, and then resize it down to what was read in the receive. That's what the `std::size_t length` is **for**

Comment: @Caleth No upper bound. I guess I'm better off with the move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot do it:

```
 asio::async_read(*m_socket, asio::buffer(tmp), asio::transfer_exactly(available)); //[1]
 tmp.insert(tmp.begin(), std::make_move_iterator(m_buffer.begin()),
                            std::make_move_iterator(m_buffer.end())); // [2]
```

in [1] asynchronous operation starts. `async_read` returns immediately. Then we have two concurrent operations, the first inserts into `tmp`, the second (asynchronous operation) fills `tmp` by some data.
You can use synchronous operation: `asio::read` instead of `asio::async_read`, the former is blocking function, so `insert` is only performed when data has been read.

---

If you don't want to play with concatenating vector, creating temporary objects etc. you can use **boost::asio::dynamic_buffer**:

```
struct listener {
 vector<char> m_buffer;
 // others members
};

void listener::read(std::function<void(std::error_code ec, packet p)> callback) 
{
  boost::asio::async_read(m_socket, boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(m_buffer), boost::asio::transfer_exactly(1),
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
             [&, callback](std::error_code ec, std::size_t length) 
             {
                 const auto available = m_socket.available();
                 boost::asio::async_read(m_socket, boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(m_buffer), 
                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                      boost::asio::transfer_exactly(available),
                   [this,callback](const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t)
                   {
                      callback(ec, std::move(m_buffer));
                   });
            });
}
```

`m_buffer` is automatically increased by *async operation*. You don't do it manually. As you can see I added the new handler -> where is called `callback(ec,move(m_buffer))`. When this handler is called we know that read operation ends.

Comment: Quick note: I had to call m_buffer.clear() before the first async_read().